# How do you say produce more noises through clapping?

Tags: word-request

How do you say produce more noises through clapping? Clapping as in hand clapping. I thought outclapped means exactly that, but it's not even a word, so I would like to know if there's any word or phrase used to say that.

Comment: Clap more, clap louder, don't stop clapping. If you really mean a comparison, I think "out-x" is considered productive, so even if it's not in a dictionary, it will be understood and idiomatic.

Comment: Heh, you posted this comment as I was writing up my answer saying almost exactly the same thing.

Comment: BTW, a car that no longer works well is *clapped out*., perhaps from the idea that someone "beat" on the car. Of course if the muffler is clapped out, it's LOUD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a single word in *common usage* that means this.  That doesn't mean we can't express the idea, just *usually* not in a single word.  Incidentally, your suggestion of "outclap" might actually work as neologism!  It's not a word in the dictionary, but it uses the prefix "out-" in an unambiguous way, and I believe both native and proficient English speakers alike would find the word to be understandable.

Outside of your lovely neologism however, **to clap** is of course the verb we need to focus on.  We just need to apply some comparative adverbs to it.  The following all work, and the parts in parenthesis are optional.

> He **clapped louder** (than someone else).

> He **clapped harder** (than someone else).

> He **clapped more** (than someone else).

Note that this last one, **clapped more** does not necessarily mean louder, but rather more repeatedly, or for a longer duration.  However, it can *imply* louder, even if it doesn't actually mean louder literally or directly.